# Applying chgrp "apache" to entire directory failed

Tags: bash, apache2

I've been tried to change group of the whole directory with code example below [bash terminal on ubuntu 11.10]:

```
chgrp apache -R ./test1
```

but failed and said :

```
chgrp: invalid group: `apache'
```

user and group in httpd.conf is set to "apache".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've installed Apache via `sudo apt-get install apache2` or with `sudo tasksel install lamp-server` then the default group is `www-data` not `apache` you'll need to use that group name instead (You may also need to update the Apache configuration file).

If you've custom compiled it, or using a 3rd party source, you will need to make sure the `apache` group actually exists. You can check by typing the following in the command line:

```
cat /etc/group | grep "apache"
```

If no results are returned then you'll need to create the group, you can do so with `sudo addgroup apache`. However, at this point I STRONGLY ADVISE you use aptitude to install Apache, as by using the apt package manager you'll always stay up to date and configuration (including group creation) will be done for you.

Comment: got it. `www-data` works. but therz a problem with part1 of your guide. i have changed `APACHE_RUN_USER`|`GROUP` to `apache` [this file: etc/apache2/envvars] and comment www-data group|user, then when tried to restart apache it said: `bad name "apache"`. why `www-data` works but my custom name is bad name ?!

Comment: @Netmoon because it must be an existing user and existing group. When you install apache from the ubuntu repositories, it will create the user `www-data` and the group `www-data` during installation. If you want to use a different user and group, you have to create them first. You can use the `addgroup` and `adduser` commands to create them.

Comment: @Netmoon Please see the second half of the answer, if you're using a custom group (not recommended), you will need to run `sudo addgroup apache`